# Can BMT transaction join with an existing transaction?

Tags: transactions, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jta

I find that in a session bean, while using Container-Managed-Transactions, the transaction can be made to join with the existing client-transaction using transactional attributes like REQUIRED / SUPPORTS.

While using Bean-Managed-Transaction, is there a way to make that transaction join with the existing client-transaction ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No (See § 13.6.1 and § 13.6.2 in the spec).

But why would you do that anyway? If the bean is meant to join a transaction started somewhere else, just make if CMT with REQUIRED. It's the same situation when a BMT bean whan to call another bean. The BMT bean controls the transaction demarcation, and the other bean uses CMT to join the transaction.

*Note also that in the spec, the term "client" refers to the caller of a bean, it can be another bean, a stand-alone client, or external client (e.g. web service request).*